# Modifying array defined in object inside function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have defined object:

```
var obj = {
    arr: [{prop1: 1}, {prop2: 2}]
}
```

Object is send to function to add some elements:

```
fnc(obj);
```

Where fnc looks like:

```
var fnc = function(p) {
    p.arr.push({prop3: 3}); // doesn't work
    p.arr[0].prop1 = 2; // works
    p.arr.length = 0; // works
}
```

The problem is, that I'm able to change the current objects of obj's array, but I'm not able to add any elements.
How can I add more elements to that array, that will be visible outside of this function?

Comment: It works for me. Why do you think it wouldn't, can you show us an explicit example how that fails?

Comment: Code looks good to me. Just put a break point after the push statement, and check if the object has been added to the array.

Comment: Why are you doing `p.arr.length = 0`? Just as an example of something that works? That's emptying your array...